# Providing custom activity name instead of main activity in android studio while creating new project

Tags: android, android-activity

I have just started learning to use Android Studio and using examples of login and registration codes given in various blogs.

Problem: Whenever I launch a new project, the default empty activity that gets loaded is named as `MainActivity`.  If I change the activity name later, it leads to various build errors.  I am using `AndroidStudio 3.3.2`.

I tried creating a project with no activity and tried adding an empty activity after the project is created.  The activity got created however, when I try to run the app, I get an error `Default activity not found`.

How do I create a project with custom name for activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it's very easy.
you can refactor the file name and Android Studio handle the errors.

[image]

Comment: thank you....with so many options to tweak in android studio...it just takes one on a virtual loop... your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Press Run > Debug Configurations and check out next

Launch: Default Activity

After it go to manifest and find activity you want to launch first. Add to it intent-filter:

```
<activity 
android:name="packageName.yourActivityName">
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```